# Issues with throwing,colliding and falling speed in ipad and ipad retina comparing with iphone using box2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I'm creating a game like fruit ninja with some differences for ipad and iphone using box2d. In iphone and iphone retina, all task are being performed correctly but in the case of ipad and ipad retina vegetables throwing, colliding and falling speed is very less compared to iphone and iphone retina. Is there any way to increase the speed? Same code is being used for iphone and ipad.

Comment: Are you creating the bodies of scaled sizes in iPad? You cannot use 100% same code for iPhone and iPad as long as you do not write scaling code 100% right.

Comment: I am using  this tutorial -" http://www.raywenderlich.com/14302/how-to-make-a-game-like-fruit-ninja-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-1 "for my game creation.

Comment: Because the iPad has roughly twice as many points in each dimension of the screen (width, height), you will have to double the amount of movement of sprites on an iPad in order for them to traverse the same % of screen size.